# Why disallow multiple citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

Why do some nations (e.g. India, as the HNQs just showed me) not allow their citizens to simultaneously hold citizenship with another nation?

What might stand to be gained from such laws?

Comment: @JoeC I am disappointed there are no interesting answers on that question

Comment: You can put bounties on that question to draw more attention to it, but there are no guarantees that will work.

Comment: There is already a question. Duplicates are discouraged. Bounties won't help much in this regard.